# Validaciones en formulario html

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, validación

de que manera puedo realizar las siguientes validaciones o restricciones en mi siguiente formulario:

index.php

Dentro de mi index.php tengo un formulario que trae desde base de datos fecha de inicio y hora de inicio ya registradas.

Adicional tengo dentro de ese mismo formulario otros dos input que permiten ingresar fecha final y hora final

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="POST">          


Hora Inicio:
<input type="time" id="horainicio" name="horainicio" value="<?php echo $datosone['horainicio']?>"/>

Fecha de Inicio:
<input type="text" id="fechainicio" name="fechainicio" value="<?php echo $datosone['fechainicio']?>"/>


<br>
Hora Final:
<input type="time" id="horafinal" name="horafinal" required />

Fecha Final:
<input type="text" id="fechafin" name="fechafin" required />

<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR"/>  
</form>
```

Lo que estoy buscando hacer es que si selecciono una fecha y hora menor a la fecha y hora inicial no me deje avanzar para registrar los datos.

De que manera podría hacerlo? es necesario que deba unificar la fecha iniciar y hora inicial igual con la fecha y hora final? o se puede validar desde el mismo formulario?

No tengo mucha idea de como podría hacerlo.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad muchas gracias amigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto te puede ayudar, agregando onsubmit al formulario esperas a que te devuelva "true" para continuar. Para la validacion puedes unir la hora y fecha y compararlas, si la fechahorainicial es mayor retornas "false". Quité algunas cosas para que esté mas limpio, puedes poner required donde quieras que sea obligatorio, y obtener la fecha hora inicial de una bd.

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
  var horai =  document.getElementById("horainicio").value;
  var horaf = document.getElementById("horafinal").value;
  var fechai = document.getElementById("fechainicio").value;
  var fechaf = document.getElementById("fechafin").value

  var k = new Date(fechai+" "+horai);
  var l = new Date(fechaf+" "+horaf);

  if (k>l) {
    return false;
  }
} 
</script> 
</head>
</body>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="POST">          


Hora Inicio:
<input type="time" id="horainicio" name="horainicio" value=""/>

Fecha de Inicio:
<input type="date" id="fechainicio" name="fechainicio" value="a" />


<br>
Hora Final:
<input type="time" id="horafinal" name="horafinal" />

Fecha Final:
<input type="date" id="fechafin" 
name="fechafin" />

<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR"/>  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Angel, lo unico que no entiendo es que en el form action="/action_page.php" esta eso, lo reemplazo por mi insertar.php cierto? y le dejo el / o lo quito? por otro lado la fecha final y hora final no pueden ser nunca menor que la fecha y hora de inicio.

Comment: Ya logre implementarlo en mi codigo y funciona perfecto como lo estaba buscando hacer muchas gracias.

Comment: Si, ahi va el php tuyo, las fechahora estan en las variables k(inicial), l(final), cada una contiene la fecha y hora correspondiente que las uní para comparar fecha y hora a la vez . Así como está "k>l" la fechahorainicial siempre debe ser mayor para continuar, si también pueden ser iguales es con ">=".

Answer (score 1):

Aqui hay un ejemplo de como validar rangos de horas.
Al formulario form le he asignado un ID y he agregado un botón para validar antes de enviar el formulario.
Cuando el input type="time" no tiene datos o esta incompleto devuelve siempre una cadena vacia.
Despues se reemplaza la hora ejemplo 12:00 eliminado el ":" para convertirlo a tipo entero y quedaria un numero comparable ejemplo 1200 entonces puedes comparar numericamente si la primer hora es menor o mayor.
Si todo esta bien se llama al submit() del formulario para que este envie los datos al servidor.

HTML CODE:

```
 <form action="insertar.php" method="POST" id="form1">
                     <input type="time" id="horaInicio" name="horaInicio" required /><br>
                <input type="time" id="horafinal" name="horafinal" required /><br>
                <input type="button" value="boton" id="btn1"/>
     </form>
```

JS CODE:

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var hinicio = document.getElementById("horaInicio").value;
        var hfinal = document.getElementById("horafinal").value;
        if (hinicio.length === 0 || hfinal.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var h1 = parseInt(hinicio.replace(":", ""), 10);
        var h2 = parseInt(hfinal.replace(":", ""), 10);
        if (h1 < h2) {
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }

    });
```